# Date period System Entity resolves to the next calendar year for non year-specific sentences

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Assuming I have a news app and I am in the year of 2018:

If the user says something like "Give me June's news", DialogFlow will resolve it to June 2019. I understand that it makes sense for some applications like event scheduling, but for my app, how can I control (train) it to resolve to the current calendar year?

Answer (score 0):

You could customize your response in a fulfillment webhook. For example, you could set up a fulfillment function that will read the value of the date system entity and perform appropriate logic.

Depending on whether you're using Actions on Google client library or Dialogflow fulfillment library, the syntax will be different. Please refer to the docs for [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/fulfillment#create_functions_to_handle_requests) or [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services#entities) on how to extract the values of entities from DialogFlow.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to train DialogFlow with what the current year is, your webhook service (logic) should make this assumption.